# System wide environment variable gets truncated

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, limit, size

On Ubuntu 16.10, I set a system wide environment variable in /etc/environment file. The variable is a string that has a length of thousands of characters (the string is a comma-separated list of small alpha codes). The problem is that the environment variable gets truncated.

Python code to generate the content of /etc/environment file with a variable named X:

```
fp = open('/etc/environment','w')
fp.write('X="' + ",".join([str(i) for i in range(2000)]) + '"')
fp.close()
```

Logout shell, login again and show environment variable

```
echo $X
```

On my machine, result is:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72

Someone told me about a 128K limit on environment variables but my variable is relatively small in length. Can anyone explain me why it gets truncated and more important, what can I do to remedy to this situation?

EDIT: output of dpkg -l libpam-modules:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                           Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-==============================================-============================-============================-==================================================================================================
ii  libpam-modules:amd64                           1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2             amd64                        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your code successfully placed the entire value in the file?

Comment: My file contains only the line X="1,2,3,...,2000"

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your situation. What shell are you using ?

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -l  libpam-modules` ? I thought the limit used by `pam_env` was 1024 characters per line.

Comment: shell used is bash

Comment: I would prefer to define system wide env variable in one place instead of in  each user's home directory

Comment: Please edit the dpkg output into the question, so it's readable; thank you!

Comment: It looks like [`pam_env`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_env/pam_env.c) from that package limits the var=value assignments to 1024 bytes each. You can get the source (`apt-get source libpam-modules`) and modify it, or modify `/etc/profile` to have your shell read in `/etc/environment` as if were shell commands.

Comment: The second solution seems easier. Can I ask you how to modify /etc/profile? Thanks again Mark.

Comment: Same problem here. Put long list of IPs and hostname (endings) in `/etc/environment` (`no_proxy` and `NO_PROXY`) + `reboot` + `echo $no_proxy` gives only 1013 characters (`no_proxy=""` is  11 chars long, makes 1024 chars). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's exactly what Mark suggested but I updated my /etc/environment file to have now the following syntax:

```
export X="1,2,..."
```

and I added a line in /etc/profile :

```
source /etc/environment
```

Don't know if it's the good way but it works.